# What does 'none' means in the list of disk space

Tags: linux, disk-space

when I ran `df -h` on my VPS server, I saw in the list there are some disk space is marked as 'none' that are 5.0M, **3.0G**, 100M. And the percentage of use is 0%. 
So what are they for, can I take back that 3.0G and allocate to? /dev/mapper/hosted--by--vg--root. I guess that is where most of my files are.

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Have a look at [this Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/questions/169495/what-are-run-lock-and-run-shm-used-for) .. they're temporary storage for various components .. usually you'll see it as `tmpfs` (vs. `none`)

Comment: @txtechhelp thanks for your link, does answer my question. Now I have another, can I reduce the 3GB to, say, 1GB, and allocate the 2GB to /dev/mapper/hosted--by--vg-root ? thanks

Comment: You can't provide the "tmpfs" / "none" files to /dev/mapper/hosted--by--vg-root because the former is RAM, the latter is actual [non-volatile] storage.